# Why does my Alpha Vantage api Call dosent work?

Tags: api, swiftui, combine

I have a question, I want to get some information about the Alpha Vantage API in my app:

*https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo*

Now it is so that my code does not work I get no errors but in the result I don't get any outputs, so could someone tell me what the problem is and correct it if possible ?

Comment: This code is not properly formatted and will simply not compile (missing curly braces, missing quotes, capitalised imports...). Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, "does not work" is a terrible problem description.  Are we trying to debug a compiler error, a crash, an error being returned from the call, bad data, ...?

Comment: @pawello2222 sorry :-(, the problem is I don't have much experience with APIs and I thought this could be a nice Example to learn it but I don't know how to start with this every example I looked used Apis that are not structured like the Api of Alpha Advantage

Comment: @pawello2222  Maybe if it is not to much, can you give me an easy example of code which fits to the Api on the Top so I can look at it and understand how this works ?